# Load Runner Application : showing internal error while updating Set LOGIN form's action tag to an error page checkbox

Tags: loadrunner

After Selecting the Set LOGIN form's action tag to an error page checkbox ,when clicked on update, it navigated me to this page:

> INTERNAL SERVER ERROR
>
> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was
>   unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator, admin@localhost and inform
>   them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done
>   that may have caused the error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error
>   log.

Pls help me how to rectify

Comment: You need to give more information. If you're scripting a web application you're perhaps not correlating session variables.

Comment: After  doing these steps without recording   when started the HP Web Tours Application which is given by default after downloading HP performance center.
. A browser opens with the
HP Web Tours home page.
1. Change the server options.
a. Click the administration link on the HP Web Tours home page. The Administration Page
opens.
b. Select the Set LOGIN form's action tag to an error page checkbox. This setting tells
the server not to allow duplicate session IDs.
c. Scroll down to the bottom of the page and click Update.i got the above error which is already given previously   @MichaelGalos